# Asignación de un puntero a array a un campo de estructura C++

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Recién arranco con C++, tema punteros y arrays y me surgió una duda con un ejercicio básico. Disculpen por tanto código, pero no encuentro otra forma de ponerlos en contexto.

Tengo una estructura entrenador, uno de sus campos es un puntero a un array de Pokemones, que representan sus Pokemon. Quisiera poder mostrar cada uno de los elementos del array. Pero me pierdo con esto de los punteros.

Los pongo en contexto con el código:

en main:

```
Pokemon* pokesE1 = new Pokemon[3];
pokesE1[0] = consPokemon("Fuego");
    pokesE1[1] = consPokemon("Fuego");
    pokesE1[2] = consPokemon("Agua");

    Entrenador e1 = consEntrenador ("Ash", 3, pokesE1); 
    mostrarEntrenador(e1);
```

implementaciones:

```
struct EntrenadorSt {
    string nombre;
    Pokemon* pokemon;
    int cantPokemon;
};

typedef EntrenadorSt* Entrenador;

struct PokemonSt {
    TipoDePokemon tipo;
    int vida;
};

typedef PokemonSt* Pokemon;


Pokemon consPokemon(TipoDePokemon tipo){
    Pokemon poke = new PokemonSt;
    poke->tipo = tipo;
    poke->vida = 100;
    return(poke);
}

Entrenador consEntrenador(string nombre, int cantidad, Pokemon* pokemones){
    Entrenador e = new EntrenadorSt;
    e->nombre = nombre;
    e->cantPokemon = cantidad;
    e->pokemon = pokemones;
    return(e);
}

void mostrarEntrenador (Entrenador e){
    cout << "Entrenador: " << endl;
    cout << "     nombre:  "<< e->nombre << endl;
    cout << "     cantidadDePokes:  "<< e->cantPokemon << endl;
    cout << "Equipo: " << endl;
    imprimirEquipo(e);
    }

void imprimirEquipo(Entrenador e){
    for (int i=0 ; i < (e->cantPokemon); i++){
        cout<< e->pokemon[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Mi duda viene el el imprimir equipo. Yo lo que quiero es mostrar el valor de cada uno de los elementos del campo pokemon, perteneciente a la estructura entrenador.
Si yo dejo
`cout<< e->pokemon[i] << endl;`
Me imprime las posiciones de memoria, lo que no se como hacer es me muestre el pokemon que esta en cada posición.

Otro caso que escapa a mi compresión es que si yo pongo;
`cout<< tipoDePokemon(e->pokemon[i]) << endl;`
Me imprime solo el tipo "Fuego" correspondiente al primer pokemon del array. Pero no imprime mas, es decir, no sigue recorriendo.

Disculpen si quizás me explico mal, estoy muy nuevo en este tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero, por legibilidad, no ocultar los punteros bajo alias que enmascaren que se trata de punteros:

```
typedef PokemonSt* Pokemon;
```

Trabajar con punteros suele ser algo complicado, de tal forma que enmascarar sus usos no hace sino dificultar su comprensión. Yo de ti eliminaría este alias.

¿Y por qué digo esto? Bueno, tu propio código es ya un buen ejemplo. ¿De qué tipo es la variable `pokemon`?

```
struct EntrenadorSt {
    string nombre;
    Pokemon* pokemon;
    int cantPokemon;
};
```

Ante nosotros tenemos un puntero doble, aunque de un primer vistazo, y salvo que te conozcas el código al dedillo lo normal es que cualquiera diga que se trata de un puntero simple. Insisto, es preferible ver el puntero doble:

```
struct EntrenadorSt {
    string nombre;
    PokemonSt** pokemon;
    int cantPokemon;
};
```

Los alias no deben utilizarse para ocultar sino facilitar la comprensión del programa. Otra cosa sería si, por ejemplo, le añadieses el sufijo `ptr`:

```
typedef PokemonSt* PokemonPtr;
```

Ahora al leer el código quedaría claro que ese tipo representa a un puntero... aunque yo sinceramente preferio no usar alias en estos casos.

> Si yo dejo cout<< e->pokemon[i] << endl; Me imprime las posiciones de memoria, lo que no se como hacer es me muestre el pokemon que esta en cada posición.

El compilador no entiende de magia. Simplemente se limita a coger código fuente y generar código ejecutable. Dicho de otra forma, solo se puede compilar aquello que el compilador conoce.

En este caso tu te has inventando un objeto de tipo `PokemonSt`. Este tipo no existe en el estándar de C++ y, por tanto, C++ no incluye ninguna sobrecarga del operador `<<` que sepa tratar punteros de tipo `PokemonSt`. Si existe, en cambio, una sobrecarga que trata punteros. Esta sobrecarga se limita a mostrar la dirección de memoria almacenada en dicho puntero... este es el comportamiento que estás experimentando.

Para sacar por pantalla el valor de las variables de `PokemonSt` debes primero implementar una sobrecarga del operador <<`:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, PokemonSt const& pokemon)
{
  os << pokemon.tipo << ' ' << pokemon.vida;
  return os;
}
```

Fíjate que esta función no recibe un puntero sino un objeto por valor. Entre otras cosas es un convenio: Si un parámetro es obligatorio, es preferible una referencia a un puntero... a una referencia no le puedes pasar, por ejemplo, `nullptr`.

Claro que ahora hay que adaptar la llamada al operador:

```
void imprimirEquipo(Entrenador e){
    for (int i=0 ; i < (e->cantPokemon); i++){
        cout<< *(e->pokemon[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

> Otro caso que escapa a mi compresión es que si yo pongo `cout<< tipoDePokemon(e->pokemon[i]) << endl;` Me imprime solo el tipo "Fuego" correspondiente al primer pokemon del array. Pero no imprime mas, es decir, no sigue recorriendo

Esto tiene que ver por la forma en la que los objetos se organizan en la memoria. Por defecto, las variables miembro de un objeto se encuentran en posiciones secuenciales de memoria, es decir, si tuviesemos alto tal que:

```
struct Test
{
    int var1;
    double var2;
};

Test t;
```

La variable `t` tendría la siguiente organización en memoria:

```
|0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03|0x04|0x05|0x06|0x07|0x08|0x09|0x0A|0x0B|
| ----- var1 ------ | ---------------- var2 --------------- |
```

Eso sí, no existe la obligación de que `var1` se encuentre justo donde *empieza* el objeto. C++ dispone de herencia, polimorfismo y funciones virtuales... todo lo necesario para que estos mecanismos funcionen corre a cargo del compilador, pero una solución a este problema pasa por incluir punteros y otra información al inicio del objeto. Esta tarea la realiza el compilador de forma totalmente transparente para el programador, pero si empiezas a hacer uso de comportamientos indeterminados te puedes acabar tropezando con este tipo de piedras.

En resumen, lo que está sucediendo aquí es que tienes la suerte que, por la forma en la que está declarada tu clase, al inicio del objeto se encuentra el puntero `TipoDePokemon`. Al forzar la conversión de `PokemonSt` a `TipoDePokemon` lo que sucede es que el compilador pasa a utilizar el objeto de tipo `PokemonSt` como si se tratase de un objeto de tipo `TipoDePokemon` y, casualmente, lo que acaba encontrando el compilador en esa posición de memoria es justamente un objeto del tipo esperado, por eso lo trata correctamente ... pero es puro azar:

```
| PokemonSt            |
| TipoDePokemon | Vida |
^
Inicio del objeto
```

Como te he dicho antes, el compilador no hace magia, se limita a hacer lo que le dices. No te va a mostrar jamás el valor de la variable `Vida` porque no le has dicho en ningún momento ni que lo tenga ni que hacer ni cómo debe hacerlo.